# How to access other projects in one solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, projects-and-solutions

I have one empty solution Store with 3 projects Store.Domain, Store.UnitTests, Store.WebUI

In domain I have my Data Model and I like to access through Store.WebUI. I try using Store.Domain however I got an error type or namespace could not be found are you missing using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: make sure you are adding project references where another project may depend on it

Comment: You need to 'Add a project reference' - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: [MSDN how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in visual studio you can right-click on your solution and then choose to add an existing project. In case you want to include the complete project.

or you can go to references and add the just the reference to your Store.Domain

Then you should be able to acces your other namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the reference section of Store.WebUI and click 'Add reference';
Select the project ' Store.Domain' and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the Store.Domain project from the Store.WebUI project.